# Converting an integer number into a binary number using recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I'm trying to write a script which converts a given integer number into a binary number using recursion. Here's the code that I've written:

```
def dec2bin(n):
    if n > 0:
        if n%2 == 0:
            li.append(0)
        else:
            li.append(1)
        return dec2bin(n/2)    
    else:
        aa = li[::-1]
        for e in aa:
            print e,    
n = int(raw_input())
li = []
dec2bin(n)
```

However, this code keeps on running and never outputs the correct answer. What seems to be the problem with this code?

Comment: `n` here isn't a decimal number, it's an `int`, which has no inherent base (or, if you want to stretch it and say it has one, the inherent base is binary).

Comment: So to be more correct this function isn't converting decimal to binary it is just printing a positive integer in binary.  That is if it worked.

Comment: Meanwhile, there are definitely problems with this code, but I can't reproduce the one you're asking about. When I try it with any value at all, it never runs forever.

Comment: `keeps on running and never outputs the correct answer` I think you are forgetting to enter an input for `raw_input()` and it just waits for your input.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi I don't understand your logic. For example, why would you append `0` if  `n` is divisible by `2`? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Marein: If it's divisible by two, that means its last bit is 0.

Comment: @Marein I have used the algorithm mentioned on the following link for my code: http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ConvertingDecimalNumberstoBinaryNumbers.html

Comment: But it's recursive, so does that stay relevant?

Comment: I ran this and got the correct answer with no changes

Comment: @Marein: Yes, because he keeps dividing by 2 (using truncating integer division), so if it's divisible by 2 in the second call, that means the second bit is a 0, and so on.

Comment: @jakekimds No, that's not the case apparently.

Comment: If this is your code, and it's not just that you forgot to type a number into the `raw_input` prompt, and it's running forever, the only thing I can think of is that there's an indentation error somewhere in your code caused by mixing tabs and spaces, which got "fixed" when you pasted the code to StackOverflow and Brad Budlong, I, and others copied it from here and pasted it ourselves. Try running it with `python -tt myscript.py` and see what it says.

Comment: Either that, or there's some edge case that breaks your code that isn't obvious, and that none of us have tested, in which case… tell us what input caused it to run forever.

Comment: Can you give an example number where your breaks?

Comment: I added the 'li = []' line before I take the number as input instead of adding after the input, and the code works just fine now. I don't really understand how this could have caused my code to not work as intended though.

Comment: If it still doesn't work for you, put a `print n` at the top inside the function so you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Brad Budlong's solution, but creating the list at the lowest level of recursion instead of using a global or a second argument.  (This is Python 3.3 so `print` is a function; adjust for Python 2.7 if desired.  Also using the // operator instead of /)

```
def dec2bin(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    else:
        r = dec2bin(n//2)
        r.append(n%2)
        return r

print(dec2bin(10))
print(dec2bin(42))
```

Comment: Nice. This is probably *the* sane solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to think about since you are investigating recursion.  If you switch the order of the append and the recursive call, then you don't have to reverse the list at the end.  This lets the recursion defer the MSB until after the LSBs have already been handled.  In the end it does the same thing, but with less complication.

```
def dec2bin(n):
    if n > 0:
        dec2bin(n/2)
        li.append(n%2)
        print n%2,
```

I also removed the return statement that you had in your code since you aren't returning anything.  This function just modifies li and prints.

Comment: @Blckknght You should try and run it and you will see that it prints MSB down to LSB.  Note that the recursive call happens before the print, so the most deeply recursive call (the MSB) prints first

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, as it does for others in the comments.

However, its use of a global variable to store results is kind of really ugly and exposing you to various interferences, I would never want to see that in production code.
Ditto for the `print`s.

You could edit it thus:

```
def dec2bin(n, li=None):
    if li is None:
        li = list()
    if n == 0:
        return li[::-1]
    else:
        if n%2 == 0:
            li.append(0)
        else:
            li.append(1)
        return dec2bin(n/2, li)    


print dec2bin(1) # [1]
print dec2bin(3) # [1, 1]
print dec2bin(8) # [1, 0, 0, 0]
print dec2bin(10) # [1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Pay special attention to that `li = list()` - see http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Also note that by replacing `li.append(0)` with `[0]+li` and doing the same for the odd case you can do without the reversing (for a small price in readability).

Comment: I'm not sure `li = [0] + li` would be any less readable… but if you think it is, why not `li.insert(0, 0)`? (Of course there _is_ a cost in performance; you're trading a linear-time reversal for quadratic-time repeatedly shifting the list… but in this use case I doubt that would ever matter, and if it did, you'd want to test it anyway; until you get to huge numbers, the incredibly low constant multiplier on shifting the list may mean it's not a problem…)

Comment: I don't know, `append` seems the most readable to me, but we *are* splitting hairs.